# Context menu to delete items from a ComboBox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, contextmenu

Currently, I've designed my own combobox from a ListBox/Button/TextBox to accomplish this, but I'm finding this to be way to much work to try and get a hacked together ComboBox to look like an actual ComboBox control.

This does however give me the desired effect however. Sort of ...

But my question is, is there not a simpler way to do this? Is there a way to simply right click on an item in a ComboBox, and get a context menu that says "Delete" for that specific entry?

Here is an example of the desired effect with my hacked together ComboBox:
[image]

I've tried simply linking a ContextMenu to a ComboBox, but that only allows for right click on the actual ComboBox itself, not the drop down, which renders this useless to me.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Some discussions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042384) on why this is not easy to implement. HTH

Comment: Hmm, that's a touch disappointing .. I'm going to keep reading and researching other ways or alternatives to accomplish this. While my hacked together ComboBox sort of works, it just doesn't feel right. Thanks for the tip.